# RHEL8 - cannot set the default session for root; config file resets after reboot

Tags: rhel, gnome, session, gdm

On my RHEL8.5 server I am trying to set the default session for root from `gnome-classic` to `gnome`.

Following [Redhat's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/user-sessions#configuring-user-default-session) (this guide is for RHEL7 but I haven't found an equivalent for RHEL8), I've edited `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/root`, from:

```
[User]
Session=gnome-classic
```

to:

```
[User]
Session=gnome
```

However this seems to have no effect on the session I'm getting. After a reboot, not only is the `gnome-classic` session still used, `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/root` has also been automatically reset to `Session=gnome-classic` which is weird and unexpected. What to do?

---

#### Things I've tried and did nothing:

Setting the default session for all users, following the guide [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5034791).

---

#### Things I've tried and did something:

I disabled GDM autologin by editing `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` and rebooted, then logged in using SSH without logging in graphically. Curiously this time `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/root` has not been reset automatically. Therefore I suspected GDM has something to do with it, but I haven't yet found anything relevant in my research.

---

#### Environment

```
# uname -msr
Linux 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64 x86_64
# gdm --version
GDM 40.0             
# gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.32.2
```

Comment: For what it’s worth, ssh’ing in ain’t going to affect GDM at all.

Comment: @jsbillings yeah I just put that there to show it's probably GDM or something related that's resetting the config file.